# Export a list of data frames in multiple Excel files containing each multiple sheets

Tags: r, excel, lapply

Apologies in advance if this has already been asked elsewhere, but I've tried different attempts and nothing has worked so far.

I have a list (named `Results`) of 26 data frames (DF). I export each DF into 26 Excel files using `writexl` and `lapply` with an anonyous function :

```
>   head(Results)
$Paris.Aquatic_moss
    Sample_type Locality Chemicals mean_Mesure max_Mesure min_Mesure 
1  Aquatic_moss   Paris   AG-110m        NA         NA         NA   
2  Aquatic_moss   Paris     BE-7      123.275      177.0      52.60  
3  Aquatic_moss   Paris      NH3         NA         NA         NA   
4  Aquatic_moss   Paris      CO         ...        ...        ...  
5  Aquatic_moss   London  AG-110m        NA         NA         NA   
6  Aquatic_moss   London     BE-7       ...        ...        ...  
7  Aquatic_moss   London     NH3        ...        ...        ...   
8  Aquatic_moss   London     CO         ...        ...        ... 

library(writexl)
lapply(names(Results), 
       function (x) write_xlsx(Results[[x]], path=paste(x, "2019.xlsx", sep="_")))
```

I obtain 26 Excel files named "nameoftheDF1_2019", "nameoftheDF2_2019",... Each Excel has one sheet named "Sheet1". But each Excel is huge. I realise that it would be much easier that each DF is itself split by the column called "Locality" and results in 26 Excel files each with different sheets.

I could split the list of 26 DF `Results` (see below) before exporting to Excel. But in this case, I do not know how to re-combine during exporting so that I remain with 26 Excel files containing each several sheets

```
Results_Locality <- split(Results,list(Results$Locality), drop=TRUE)
```

So I am wondering whether it is possible to add with `lapply`  another function to split `Results` by the column "Localization" so that each DF will be exported in an Excel file with different sheets (sheet1 = Localization1 in DF1, sheet2 = Localization 2 in DF1, ...) ?
Otherwise is it possible to create a loop to export the data of each localization in each DF in the same sheet ?

Comment: take alook at `data.table::split()`.. it can split a data-table by column-values and outputs to a list you can loop over with.

Comment: I am not sure to quite understand. R returns me an error :`Error: 'split' is not an exported object from 'namespace:data.table'`

Comment: my apologies... data.table comes with it's own split methods, but it is not a separate function, you can just call 'split' on a data.table... split.data.table will then be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by splitting the df and passing the splitted df to `writexl::write_xlsx`. By default `write_xlsx` will put the elements of the list in different sheets:

```
library(writexl)

xlexport <- function(x, var = "Locality") {
  d <- split(Results[[x]], Results[[x]][[var]])
  writexl::write_xlsx(d, path = paste(x, "2019.xlsx", sep = "_"))
}

Results <- list(iris1 = iris, iris2 = iris)

lapply(names(Results), xlexport, var = "Species")
```